PHPMailer internal server error (error 500) Assitance Needed
Getting an error 500 (server side error) when I try to run a simple PHPMailer script.  I have proofread and re-proofread my code looking for syntax errors but do not see any.  The include file path is correct - I checked and double checked the path.  Any ideas on why I get the error?
I am using my hosting server to send the email.  My host says everything is fine on their end (it is not Godaddy, it is Knownhost).  The mail port is correct, confirmed with Knownhost.
To keep it simple I only have this 1 script which is giving the error 500
Everything ***** is a placeholder where I removed sensitive information for this post.
Thanks
<?php
include("../lib/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php"); 

//Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
//These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
$email = "test@test.com";
$username = "test";
//Create an instance; passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      //Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'mail.*****.com';                     //Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = '*****@*****.com';                     //SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = '*****';                               //SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;            //Enable implicit TLS encryption
    $mail->Port       = 465;                                    //TCP port to connect to; use 587 if you have set `SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('noreply@*****.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress($email, $username);     //Add a recipient
    $mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               //Name is optional
    $mail->addReplyTo('noreply@*****.com', 'Information');

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'DestroyMyApp Registration Validation';
    $mail->Body    = 'Test';     
    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
} ?>

Thank you ahead of time
Update: after reading the first few comments below I re-installed PHPmailer using composer.  I then modified the paths so they are appropriate and I put the namespaces at the top of the document.  So the top 1/3 of the above script is now pasted below - I still get an error 500.  No change.
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require '../vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
require '../vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require '../vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';
require '../vendor/autoload.php';

//Create an instance; passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
....

thanks

Better load Composer's autoloader by a require statement (e.g. something like require 'vendor/autoload.php')

I did a manual installation as per the instructions.  Should work with a manual install regardless.

If you prefer to do a "manual installation" (without using composer) , then please require
/ include the necessary php files correctly . You may refer to this post and this post

Check the PHP error log to see what the actual error is. 500 error is too generic.

Thanks for replying.  I re-installed using Composer and changed the respective paths, I also swapped the namespaces so they are at the top of the document.  Still no change.. error 500

Thank you so much for your help Barmar and Ken Lee!  The path to the PHPmailer.php src was incorrect... I was still 1 folder too deep.. by adding another "../../" I was able to include the appropriate files... now it works.  Thank you thank you thank you!  Reviewing the error logs worked.  Thanks again
